# Let l be a list, would len(l) be considered an int?

Tags: python

If l = [1,2,3,4,] and we did len(l), then len(l) would be int or a list ?

Thanks,

Comment: Why not just try it out and see?

Comment: Or even better read the doc?

Answer (score 1):

an easy way to find out is by using `type()`,

```
print(type(len(l)))
```

You should find the answer.

Comment: Perfect, I was right all along !

Comment: Hope you won the bet!